# What do these two onload methods have a different approach & which is better

Tags: javascript

I was just writing an `onload` function when I stumbled across [loadCSS](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS). Its onloadcss function works in a different way.

### My function

```
var onLoadElement = function(element, callback) {

    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener("load", callback, 0);
    } else if (element.readyState) {
        element.onreadystatechange = callback;
    } else {
        element.onload = callback;
    }
}
```

### loadcss's function

```
function onloadCSS( ss, callback ) {
    ss.onload = function() {
        ss.onload = null;
        if( callback ) {
            callback.call( ss );
        }
    };
    // No support for onload:
    // Weak inference targets Android < 4.4
    if( "isApplicationInstalled" in navigator && "onloadcssdefined" in ss ) {
        ss.onloadcssdefined( callback );
    }
}
```

Clearly it has added android support but I am unclear of why `ss.onload= callback` is not used instead of the following snippet.

```
 ss.onload = null;
 if( callback ) {
     callback.call( ss );
 }
```

I've tried to tweak my function to include the non support for `.onload` but I would like to know whether to modify it further.

```
var onLoadElement = function(element, callback) {

    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener("load", callback, false);
    } else if (element.readyState) {
        element.onreadystatechange = callback;
    } else if(element.onload){
        element.onload = callback;
    } else if( "isApplicationInstalled" in navigator && "onloadcssdefined" in element ) {
        element.onloadcssdefined( callback );
    }
}
```

Update

Thanks Mike-C for your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35043326/2273611), I now understand its loadCSS's approach could be to save on memory.

So in theory this could reduce memory usage and have better browser support??

```
var onLoadElement = function(element, callback) {

    if(typeof callback !== 'function') return;

    if (element.addEventListener) {
        var cb = function(){
            callback.call( element );
            element.removeEventListener("load", cb)
        }
        element.addEventListener("load", cb, false);
    } else if (element.readyState) {
        element.onreadystatechange = function(){
            element.onreadystatechange = null;
            callback.call( element );
        }
    } else if(element.onload){
        element.onload = function(){
            element.onload = null;
            callback.call( element );
        }
    } else if( "isApplicationInstalled" in navigator && "onloadcssdefined" in element ) {
        element.onloadcssdefined( callback );
    }
}
```

Good or bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their approach handles older browsers (all of the `if(element.addEventListener)` stuff) and removes the event handler after the load completes. This may save on memory as it allows the callback and event handler to be garbage collected.

**Update:**

Yes, your new approach now handles older browsers and should save memory since you don't have dangling event handlers.